# Emil Artin's proof for Wedderburn's Little Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am looking through different proofs for Wedderburn's Little Theorem, which states that every finite division ring is necessarily a field.

I would like to read Emil Artin's proof for this theorem:

Emil Artin, Über einen Satz von Herm J. H. Maclagan Wedderburn, Hamb. Abh. 5 (1928), 245-250.

I have found the paper, but unfortunately, I can't read German. Does anyone know if there is a translation for this paper? If such translation exists, I would love to know where it can be found.

Thanks!

Comment: For your project, another proof due to Bender is in Doerk–Hawkes: http://books.google.com/books?id=E7iL1eWB1TkC&lpg=PA108

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks Jack. I will add the name to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would love to help, but until now I could not lay my hands on the German version, nor find any translations :S Here is what I did come up with during my own searches.

It might be a long shot, but Artin proves Wedderburn's theorem in his 1957 book *Geometric Algebra*. If by chance he used the same approach, then having that English version alongside the German might help.

I also found an article by Artin entitled *[The influence of J. H. M. Wedderburn on the
development of modern algebra](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1950-56-01/S0002-9904-1950-09346-X/S0002-9904-1950-09346-X.pdf)* in which discusses the theorem at one point and alludes to elements of his own proof.

I found [this interesting article](http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/mad/Wedderburn/Wedderburn.pdf) on the history of the theorem, including some sketches of what Artin's approach was. It doesn't look like it's been published in a journal, but the contents sound OK.

Comment: I never thought this question would get answered. Thank you very much :) I am going to check out "Geometric Algebra" first. And these are very nice articles. The second one gives a remarkable chronological list near the end! Which gives me opportunity to look for and read new proofs of this theorem. (Currently, Meixner's proof (1989) sounds cool!)