# Hilbert's 17th Problem - Artin's proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, rational-functions

In [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-ismp/61_schmuedgen-konrad.pdf) expository article, it is mentioned that Emil Artin proved Hilbert's 17th problem in his paper:

> E. Artin, Uber die Zerlegung definiter Funktionen in Quadrate, Abh.
>   math. Sem. Hamburg 5(1927), 110–115.

Not being able to speak German, my question is

> Does anyone know if English translation of this paper exists somewhere? Or perhaps some link to a book (or article, blog post, etc.) where this proof is given in English?

My google searches have been in vain. Note that I am only interested in Artin's proof. (There is a [algorithmic proof](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388465) due to Dellzel, which *is* in English).

Thanks!

P.S. I have [previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323151/emil-artins-proof-for-wedderburns-little-theorem) for English translation of another paper by E. Artin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this:

The Honors Class: Hilbert's Problems and Their Solvers [Paperback]
Ben Yandell

It's available on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). From what it seems like, this book discusses the solvers and history of the problems, rather than actually showing the proofs (of the solved problems) Please correct me if I am wrong.